# How to mock a method that taks a predicate with Rhino Mocks

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, rhino-mocks

I have the following repo Interface with the FindBy method taking in a predicate

```
 public interface IRepo<T> where T : class
{
    IList<T> GetAll();
    IList<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
}
```

I am trying to test that my controller does in fact call this method. Here is my controller code

```
  // GET:/Assets/EditAssets
    public PartialViewResult EditAsset(Guid id)
    {
        var asset = _assetRepo.FindBy(ass => ass.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (asset == null)
        {
            return PartialView("NotFound");
        }

        SetUpViewDataForComboBoxes(asset.AttachedDeviceId);
        return PartialView("EditAsset", asset);
    }
```

and here is my test method

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void editAsset_EmptyRepo_CheckRepoCalled()
    {
        //Arrange
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();

        var stubAssetRepo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepo<Asset>>();
        stubAssetRepo.Stub(x => x.FindBy(ass => ass.Id == id)).Return(new List<Asset> {new Asset()});

        var adminAssetsControler = new AdminAssetsController(stubAssetRepo, MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepo<AssetModel>>(), MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepo<AssetSize>>(), MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepo<AssetType>>(), MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepo<Dept>>(), MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepo<Device>>());

        //Act
        var result = adminAssetsControler.EditAsset(id);

        //Assert
        stubAssetRepo.AssertWasCalled(rep => rep.FindBy(ass => ass.Id == id));
    }
```

But I am getting an argumentNullException. I have done this kinda of test before on methods that don't predicates and it works fine. So what is going on with this one?

Is there a good way to set up this kind of test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to avoid the Null reference exception you could just use `IgnoreArguments()`:

```
stubAssetRepo.Stub(x => x.FindBy(null)).Return(new List<Asset> {new Asset()}).IgnoreArguments()
```

The thing is that you might want to verify the lambda passed to the FindBy method, and it's argument. You could do this by using `WhenCalled()` method which you can forward the lambda to another method as explained [here](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=214).
The complete code would look something like:

```
          ...
                stubAssetRepo.Stub(x => x.FindBy(null)).Return(new List<Asset> {new Asset()}).
    IgnoreArguments().WhenCalled(invocation => FindByVerification((Expression<Func<Asset, bool>>)invocation.Arguments[0]));
        ....

            //Act
            var result = adminAssetsControler.EditAsset(id);

            //Assert
            stubAssetRepo.VerifyAllExpectations();
        }

        public void FindByVerification(Expression<Func<Asset, bool>> predicate)
        {
            // Do your FindBy verification here, by looking into
            // the predicate arguments or even structure
        }
```